# How do eternal security believers explain these 2 scenarios?

Tags: soteriology, satan, adam-and-eve, assurance-of-salvation, perseverance-of-saints

I'm an eternal security believer but I'm struggling with how I should reconcile this with these two scenarios:

1. Lucifer falling from Heaven, losing his standing before God and becoming the Adversary that we now infamously know (i.e. Satan).
2. Adam and Eve spiritually dying the moment that they ate the fruit from the tree of the knowledge of the good and evil, despite being spiritually alive before. Hence, why all humans need to be "born again", per John 3:3.

Were these 2 individuals the only individuals in the Bible to have "lost their salvation/right standing with God"? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Good question!  However, practically speaking it seems to be nearly identical to one that has already been asked.  See the linked duplicate, and feel free to comment or edit here if you feel you can distinguish your question from that one.  Thanks!

Comment: Great! I just learned 2 new concepts: covenant of works and covenant of grace =). Not sure whether to ask you here or on the other link but did the "elect" officially appear for us creations, when God announced the "seed of the woman" and the "seed of the serpent"?

Comment: Technically, if Adam is in heaven today, then he was one of the elect under the covenant of grace since the beginning of time – before he sinned.  This might be confusing, but Calvinists believe that God, knowing that Adam would fail the test, predestined his children to salvation under a covenant of grace, even before Adam fell and ushered in that covenant.